# Can I get iPhone messages through my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am wondering if there is any way I can get my iPhone messages to come in through my messages on my Mac computer?

My iPhone is not working at the moment and has to get the battery replaced so it won't turn on.

Comment: Do you mean specifically iMessages, or also text messages (SMSs)?

Answer (score 4):

Messages.app on OS X can sync messages from iPhone your to the app. This only works when your phone is on the same Wi-Fi network.

So if your phone is getting repaired, you will only receive iMessages (messages sent font an iPhone/iPad/Mac to another iPhone/iPad/Mac), and not SMS texts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to voice mail, the only way of retrieving them that I'm aware of is through your cellular provider. For example, Verizon has a way that you can dial in to your voice mail from another phone, but you'll have to refer to their documentation on how to specifically do that and might even require a call to customer service if you never set up a password.

iMessages, as pointed out in another answer, can be configured to work in your Mac's Messages.app program as long as they're both on iCloud with the same credentials. Normal SMS text messages, however, require your iPhone to be functional, connected to the cell network and on the same WiFi network as your Mac and both running the latest OSs: iOS 8.x and OSX 10.10.x. You would have had to set up both the mobile and the desktop to allow for text message forwarding and done the "one time code validation" routine.